# Laravel skips installation and Could not scan for classes inside

Tags: node.js, laravel, composer-php, laravel-5.6, homestead

I have one project that is running in mac book with laravel homestead
Laravel 5.6
Virtualbox 5.2
node js versions 10.8.0

```
git clone https://github.com/laravel/homestead.git ~/Homestead
cd ~/Homestead
git checkout v7.16.1
```

Composer 1.8.5

Same setup is working on any man book
But when i try to install all software in windows
everything went correctly Except

When i'm tring to run composer install inside of homestead in my project dir
I'm getting following errors

```
Skipped installation of bin bin/doctrine-dbal for package doctrine/dbal: file not found in package  
Skipped installation of bin Resources/bin/var-dump-server for package symfony/var-dumper: file not found in package    
Skipped installation of bin bin/php-parse for package nikic/php-parser: file not found in package
```

Installation failed, reverting ./composer.json to its original content.

```
  [RuntimeException]
  Could not scan for classes inside "/home/vagrant/sites/emsadmin/vendor/sebastian/object-enumerator/src/" which does
   not appear to be a file nor a folder
```

Also i'm getting error in **npm run watch**

**I have tried so many commands but no luck**

Comment: try removing your `vendor` folder and then executing `composer install`

Comment: tried so many time ... so many things form 2 days no luck

Comment: Anything is related to network or cache or OS change issue?

Comment: I'm only getting this problem when switching from mac to windows10

Answer (score 0):

Update your Homestead, Vagrant and most importantly to VirtualBox (to v6). I had same issue with another side effect, updating to VirtualBox v6 solved it for me.

See this GitHub issue. https://github.com/laravel/homestead/issues/1219